# Converting Ruby code to C++ not generating correct output

Tags: c++, ruby, code-conversion

Since I have been searching for the best algo for maze generation in c++. I could found its implementation in Ruby from the [link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/2/1/maze-generation-binary-tree-algorithm)

Here is the code in Raw form

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# An implementation of the "Binary Tree" algorithm. This is perhaps
# the simplest of the maze generation algorithms to implement, and the
# fastest to run, but it creates heavily biased mazes.
#
# It is novel in that it can operate without any state at all; it only
# needs to look at the current cell, without regard for the rest of
# the maze (or even the rest of the row). Thus, like Eller's algorithm
# it can be used to generate mazes of infinite size.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Allow the maze to be customized via command-line parameters
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

width  = (ARGV[0] || 10).to_i
height = (ARGV[1] || width).to_i
seed   = (ARGV[2] || rand(0xFFFF_FFFF)).to_i

srand(seed)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Set up constants to aid with describing the passage directions
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

N, S, E, W = 1, 2, 4, 8
DX         = { E => 1, W => -1, N =>  0, S => 0 }
DY         = { E => 0, W =>  0, N => -1, S => 1 }
OPPOSITE   = { E => W, W =>  E, N =>  S, S => N }

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Data structures to assist the algorithm
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

grid = Array.new(height) { Array.new(width, 0) }

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. A simple routine to emit the maze as ASCII
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

def display_maze(grid)
  print "\e[H" # move to upper-left
  puts " " + "_" * (grid[0].length * 2 - 1)
  grid.each_with_index do |row, y|
    print "|"
    row.each_with_index do |cell, x|
      if cell == 0 && y+1 < grid.length && grid[y+1][x] == 0
        print " "
      else
        print((cell & S != 0) ? " " : "_")
      end

      if cell == 0 && x+1 < row.length && row[x+1] == 0
        print((y+1 < grid.length && (grid[y+1][x] == 0 || grid[y+1][x+1] == 0)) ? " " : "_")
      elsif cell & E != 0
        print(((cell | row[x+1]) & S != 0) ? " " : "_")
      else
        print "|"
      end
    end
    puts
  end
end

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. Binary Tree algorithm
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

print "\e[2J" # clear the screen

height.times do |y|
  width.times do |x|
    display_maze(grid)
    sleep 0.02

    dirs = []

    dirs << N if y > 0
    dirs << W if x > 0

    if (dir = dirs[rand(dirs.length)])
      nx, ny = x + DX[dir], y + DY[dir]
      grid[y][x] |= dir
      grid[ny][nx] |= OPPOSITE[dir]
    end
  end
end

display_maze(grid)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Show the parameters used to build this maze, for repeatability
# --------------------------------------------------------------------

puts "#{$0} #{width} #{height} #{seed}"
```

I have converted this code in cpp as:

```
#include "iostream"
#include<cstdlib>
#include"time.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct Point{
    int E;
    int W;
    int N;
    int S;

    int getElementAt(int i)
    {
        if (i == 4)
            return E;
        else if (i == 8)
            return W;
        else if (i == 1)
            return N;
        else if (i == 2)
            return S;

    }
};


class Maze
{
private:
    int width, height, seed;
    int N, S, E, W;
    Point DX, DY, OPPOSITE;
    int **grid;

public:
    Maze()
    {
        width = 10; //maze height
        height = 10;    //maze width

        //seed = rand() % RAND_MAX + 1; //random number assignment to seed
        srand(time(NULL));

        E = 4, W = 8, N = 1, S = 2;

        DX = { 1, -1, 0, 0 };   //it will keep the directions of each point on X
        DY = { 0, 0, -1, 1 }; //it will keep the directions of each point on Y
        OPPOSITE = { W, E, S, N };
        grid = new int*[height];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            grid[i] = new int[width];
            for (int ini = 0; ini < width; ini++)
            {
                grid[i][ini] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void display_maze()
    {
        cout << "[H";
        for (int i = 0; i < width * 2 - 1; i++)
        {
            cout << "_";
        }

        cout << endl;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            cout << "|";
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (grid[y][x] == 0 && y + 1 < height && grid[y + 1][x] == 0)
                    cout << " ";
                else
                    cout << ((grid[y][x] & S != 0) ? " " : "_");

                if (grid[y][x] == 0 && x + 1 < height && grid[y][x + 1] == 0)
                    cout << ((y + 1 < height && (grid[y + 1][x] == 0 || grid[y + 1][x + 1] == 0)) ? " " : "_");
                else if (grid[y][x] & E != 0)
                    cout << (((grid[y][x] | grid[y][x + 1]) & S != 0) ? " " : "_");
                else
                    cout << "|";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    void generate()
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < height)
        {
            int x = 0;
            while (x < width)
            {
                display_maze();
                vector<int> dirs;;
                if (y > 0)
                    dirs.push_back(N);
                if (x > 0)
                    dirs.push_back(W);

                srand(time(NULL));


                int zz = rand() % (dirs.size() - 0 + 1) + 0;
                if (zz < dirs.size())
                {
                    int dir = dirs[zz];
                    int nx = x + DX.getElementAt(dir);
                    int ny = y + DY.getElementAt(dir);
                    grid[y][x] |= dir;
                    grid[ny][nx] |= OPPOSITE.getElementAt(dir);
                }

            x++;
        }

        y++;
    }
}

};

void main()
{
    Maze maze;
    //maze.display_maze();
    maze.generate();
    //maze.display_maze();
}
```

I have converted the **ruby** script below display_maze to  **generate()** function. I have also converted **DX,DY,OPPOSITE** to struct to reuse them easily.

The problem occurs in **generate()** of cpp since if (dir = dirs[rand(dirs.length)]) If i use this thing in c++ it throw index out of bound exception. I have checked through if statement.

But both of my codes generate different outputs. Please run both seperately. The **display function** seems to work fine. Problem is with **generate()** method only!

**Edit:**

Code is working fine but I cannot figure out the problem why maze generates differently. My ruby code give exact output but c++ code does not generate output correctly. I am unable to get the issue!

Comment: You've got a stray `}` at the end of your class, there. Put your code through an automatic formatter - there's an online one [here](format.krzar.cc). Often it will show your code isn't logically arranged the way you think it is!

Comment: Also you **must** use `int main()` not `void main()`. Not sure where `void` comes from, it's often in sample code here, but it's not valid C++.

Comment: I recommend you compile your code with the `clang` compiler, because it has the best warning/error messages. There's an online one [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox). Just paste your code in, try to compile, and it will give you really useful warnings and errors along with hints about how to fix.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the suggestions but problem is I am unable to find the logic difference between two. Since they are same than why cpp code generates different output?

Comment: "If i use this thing in c++ it throw index out of bound exception." Are you expecting Ruby arrays and C++ arrays (or vectors) to behave identically? Are you expecting your Ruby and C++ programs to produce identical output even they both use random numbers? Even when there's no reason to think that Ruby and your C++ standard library use the same pseudo-random number algorithms with identical seeds?

Comment: I have used vector in c++ instead of array and in case of random numbers it's working fine.